# Higher powers of logarithms in summations over primes connected to R.H

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I know from Dusart papers and other similar paper that $c_0+ \ln \ln \theta(x) \leq \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} $ and $ c_1 +\ln \theta(x) \leq \sum \limits_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln p}{p}$ are equivalent to R.H. due to Robin and Nicolas($c_0,c_1$ are explicit in the papers but not relevant to the question).

I want to generalize these inequalities, so given a polynomial with respect to $\ln p$ such as $\ln^2 p -2 \ln p $ or $ \ln^3 p +3 \ln^2 p -7 \ln p+2$ is the related inequality equivalent to R.H. ?

To clarify what i mean by related inequality lets take for instance the polynomial(with respect to $\ln p$) $Q(p) = \ln^2 p -5 \ln p  $ so the related inequality is $ \frac{\ln^2 \theta(x)}{2}-5 \ln \theta(x) + c_2 \leq \sum \limits_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln^2 p-5\ln p}{p}$ is  equivalent to R.H. !

Fact : for linear polynomials with respect to $\ln p$ the answer is yes due to Robin and Nicolas.

Note :  this question was posted on MSE and i put bounty on an answer with no success, i am interested in an answer or a ref to published paper(s).

Edit : [The question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865957/higher-power-of-logarithms-connected-to-robin-and-nicolas-inequalities)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What makes the titled formula by Robine and Nicolas  so good because the given formula is simple and clear that is related to prime number theorem , and just you need to do small comparaison between $\ln^2 p-5\ln p$ and $ \ln p$  for large $ p $ , what I think you would have  $\ln^2 p-5\ln p \sim  \ln p, p \to \infty $ then you will have the same  inequality of Robine and Nicholas , I think you need some motivation to your question why you need  your inequality in that form to be equivalent to RH ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik not just the form $\ln^2 p -5 \ln p $ but if you let $ t = \ln p$ then any polynomial of $t $, $t^2 -5t$ is just one example.